# Different roles and routing for one single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a `User` model.

It is managed in two user cases:
1. by the user herself under the namespace `admin`
2. by the administrator of the website under the namespace `super_admin`

Should I create two `UsersControllers`, one each for the two namespaces? (Otherwise, how else?)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the gem [the_role](https://github.com/the-teacher/the_role) with great success. I like how easy it is to create different roles and then manage them. You can match roles up with controller actions, and there are all sorts of handy methods like `has_role?`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the recommendation, but right now I'm mainly concerned about the design aspect of what structure hierarchy I should go for (regarding the action_pack).